# How to get the content of the current buffer in vim command mode?

Tags: vim

There is a vim function `Send_to_Screen(text)` which sends some text to a console screen session. I have a mapping

```
vmap <F4> "ry :call Send_to_Screen(@r)<CR>
```

which calls the function with the current selection. Now I want do define another mapping which calls the function with the contents of the whole buffer, but I don't get it to work. I tried

```
nmap <F5> maggVG"ry`a :call Send_to_Screen(@r)<CR>
```

but it doesn't work. So how do I define the mapping with the text of the current buffer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
nmap <F5> :call Send_to_Screen(join(getline(1,'$'), "\n"))<CR>
```

The function `getline()` returns a list of lines in the selected range (1 is the first line and "$" is the last) and the function `join()` joins the contents of a list together with the provided separator ("\n" in this case).  See:

```
:help getline()
:help join()
```

Comment: Any difference between single and double quotes in vimscript?

Comment: @qed single quotes won't interpret `\n` as a newline but a literal `\n`